# Issue with rotateY(90deg) in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, webkit-perspective

I have a "scene" `div` that contains a "plane" `div` perpendicular to the scene.

If I rotate the "scene" `div` on the Y axis by 90 degrees I should see the "plane" `div` in its entirety (as it happens Chrome) but Safari makes it disappear. The same happens at 270 degrees, but starts working past a full revolution of the scene (450deg, 630deg, etc.).
I tried setting some translateZ() on the elements but I think I didn't find the right combination.

Is there a way to make it work in at < 360deg?

(I actually encountered this behaviour in a more involved scenario, but I think this is the root cause of the problem)

edit: added a code snippet

```js
const scene = document.querySelector(".scene");
const rotateBtn = document.querySelector(".rotate-btn");

let rotation = 0;

rotateBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  rotation += 30;
  scene.style.transform = `rotateY(${rotation}deg)`;
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.scene {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.plane {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20rem;
  height: 30rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.plane-1 {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: red;
}

.plane-2 {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateY(90deg);
  background: blue;
  backface-visibility: visible;
}

.rotate-btn {
  position: fixed;
  top: 1rem;
  left: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Safari 3D Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="scene">
        <div class="plane plane-1"></div>
        <div class="plane plane-2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="rotate-btn">rotate</button>
  </body>
</html>
```